# Free Objects and Equational classes

Tags: universal-algebra

I can't give a proof of this fact:
"Given a non-empty set $X$ and an equational class $V$, then $V$ contains a free object on $X$."
$V$ is a class of algebras of a certain language of algebras $L$ and $V$, qua equational class, is $M(\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is a set of identities and $M(\Sigma))$ indicates the class of $L$-algebras satisfying $\Sigma$.
I wanna show that the couple $((W_{X},\Sigma),F)$ is an $L$-algebra, where $W_{X}$ is the set of words in the alphabet $X$ and with the only relations between words are given by $\Sigma$ and $F$ is the set of operations on $W_{X}$ given by the language $L$. The problem is: how to define $F$? Is this the right way to prove this fact? I don't know much about cathegory theory so I am trying this way.

Comment: $F$ should be defined beforehand. Otherwise, how do you define the equations that determine $V$?

Comment: Ok now maybe it's more clear.
Let X a non-empty set and $L$ a language of algebras and $L_{i}$ the function symbols in $L$ of arity i.
I define the set of terms of X, T(X) as the smallest set such that:
1) $X \cup L_{0} \subset T(X)$ ;
2)If $p_{1},...,p_{n} \in T(X)$ and $f \in L_{n}$ then $f(p_{1},...,p_{n}) \in T(X)$.
Now I define an identity of type $L$ on $X$ as an ordered pair $(p,q)$, where $p,q \in T(X)$.
Now the free object on X in the language $L$ is the pair $(W,F)$ where $W$ is the set of words on T(X) with relations given by $\Sigma$ and operations are "just strings".

Comment: I continue here. Operations $F$ are just the eveluation in $W$ of function symbols in $L$. Does this have sense? The way in which opertions work depends only from $\Sigma$, am I right?

Comment: Well, it seems that you are skipping one step: you have to take the quotient of $T(X)$ by the congruence generated by the identities satisfied in $V$. Otherwise you just get the free object of the given type, but perhaps the variety $V$ is only a sub variety of that, I mean, if it satisfies some identities. For example, if the type consists of one binary operation, and $V$ is the variety of semigroups, then you have to take the quotient of $T(X)$ by $\Theta(x(yz),(xy)z)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check, for example, [this book of Universal Algebra](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf), Definition II.10.9